# Spring boot 2 JPA : database pool validation query taking long time

Tags: sql-server, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, connection-pooling

I have Spring boot 2 applications, when I am firing a select query, before actual query runs one validation query `"SELECT 1"` is being called because of DB pool wants to validate if the pooled connection is alive or not,

`"Select 1"` is also taking long time, what can be done to improve performance, of course disabling `"Select 1"` validation is not a good idea

```
2019-10-01 20:54:43.352 DEBUG 15196 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] org.hibernate.SQL                        : 
    /* SELECT
        MY Hibernate Query
2019-10-01 20:54:43.354 DEBUG 15196 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] c.m.s.jdbc.internals.SQLServerStatement  : SQLServerStatement:7 created by (ConnectionID:1 ClientConnectionId: 5494adca-2bef-4403-bcb6-713b676df4fd)
2019-10-01 20:54:43.354 DEBUG 15196 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] c.m.s.jdbc.internals.SQLServerStatement  : SQLServerStatement:7 Executing (not server cursor) SELECT 1
2019-10-01 20:54:43.612 DEBUG 15196 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] c.m.s.jdbc.internals.SQLServerResultSet  : SQLServerResultSet:7 created by (SQLServerStatement:7)
2019-10-01 20:54:43.647 DEBUG 15196 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] c.m.s.jdbc.internals.SQLServerStatement  : SQLServerPreparedStatement:8 created by (ConnectionID:1 ClientConnectionId: 5494adca-2bef-4403-bcb6-713b676df4fd)
2019-10-01 20:54:43.740 TRACE 15196 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [1] as [VARCHAR] - [US]
2019-10-01 20:54:43.766 DEBUG 15196 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] c.m.s.jdbc.internals.SQLServerStatement  : SQLServerPreparedStatement:8: calling sp_executesql: SQL:/* SELECT c.shippingZone.currency.isoName FROM Country c WHERE c.id = :countryCode  */ select currency2_.ISO_NAME as col_0_0_ from TBL_COUNTRY country0_ left outer join TBL_SHIPPING_ZONE_COUNTRY country0_1_ on country0_.ID=country0_1_.COUNTRY_ID cross join TBL_SHIPPING_ZONES shippingzo1_ cross join TBL_CURRENCIES currency2_ where country0_1_.SHIPPING_ZONE_ID=shippingzo1_.ID and shippingzo1_.CURRENCY_ID=currency2_.ID and country0_.ID=@P0        
2019-10-01 20:54:44.029 DEBUG 15196 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] c.m.s.jdbc.internals.SQLServerResultSet  : SQLServerResultSet:8 created by (SQLServerPreparedStatement:8)
2019-10-01 20:54:44.043 DEBUG 15196 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] org.hibernate.loader.Loader              : Result set row: 0
2019-10-01 20:54:44.044 DEBUG 15196 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] org.hibernate.loader.Loader              : Result row:
```

Comment: Which pool are you using?

Comment: Hikari connection pooling

Comment: Then don't use a validation query. Hikari has better was (JDBC4 actually) for checking connection validity. Please add the configuration to your question (datasource and hibernate).